# Meaning - lawin'

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

> As Calpurnia, one
>   Miscellany 195
>   character in the story, notes, ‘First thing you learn when you’re in a **lawin’** family is that there
>   ain’t any definite answers to anything.’

I hazard that this quote reflects a colloquial southern US accent, yet can't deduce the word proper.

Origin: To Kill A Mockingbird (1960), by Harper Lee
Source: P195, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Comment: Perhaps 'family of lawyers'? 'A banking family' probably sounds acceptable, but the attributive version 'a lawyering family' sounds at best tongue-in-cheek to me.

Comment: My first thought was of law enforcement, but the protagonist of the origin "To Kill a Mockingbird" was a lawyer, so "lawing" is likely the colloquial term for "practicing law" so it parses to "...in a family that practices law..." as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/106408?rskey=sWhdja&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid) [subscriber-only link] has *law* as a verb:

> **2.a.** *intr.* To go to law, litigate. Also **to law it.** Also *colloq.* or *dial.* in indirect passive.
>
> > ?a1550   *Hye Way to Spyttel Ho.* 799 in W. C. Hazlitt *Remains Early Pop. Poetry Eng.* IV. 59   They that lawe for a debt vntrew.
> >     1866   ‘G. Eliot’ *Felix Holt* I. Introd. 13   People who inherited estates that were lawed about.
>
> **b.** *trans.* To go to law with, proceed against in the courts.
>
> > 1647   J. Trapp *Comm. Epist. & Rev.* (1 Cor. vi. 7)   By your litigious lawing one another, you betray a great deal of weaknesse.
> >     1870   E. Peacock *Ralf Skirlaugh* II. 117   You can't law a man ye knaw for a job like that.

Calpurnia's use of *lawing* appears to have this meaning, or a meaning very closely related. The family is a family involved in the law and litigation, and lawyers are renowned for making use of any nuances of meaning they find advantageous — meaning that very little is entirely clear-cut in any argument.

That entry was first published in 1902 and doesn't appear to have had a great deal of attention since then, so if the use of *law* as a verb fell out of use around that time then it wouldn't be recorded as obsolescent. Smaller dictionaries which have been updated since then might not list the use at all if it turns up so rarely that it's no longer worth including.

However, an obsolescent use can often survive in local dialects.

Comment: I'd add a nuance: it's a family where the members tend to think like lawyers, pretty much as laid out above.  I've applied the expression (derived from the book) to my own family often enough, though only my father was actually a lawyer, and he wasn't in practice -- he taught law.